# Compile openCV with SIFT and python 2.7 bindings without root privileges

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, opencv

I am using a shared cluster sever where I can only install libraries locally. On that cluster I tired to install openCV with SIFT (contrib) and python 2.7 bindings.

- Do I get it right that openCV should always be compiled?
- Is there a good way using a package manager? I tried it with pip, but because another version of openCV is already installed it seems that I cannot install another locally.

Comment: by pip you get a pretty old opencv probably 2.4.9 now if you want to install the latest one 3.1.0 or the 3.0.0  you have to build it and the contrib to get the contrib modules. You can follow this ->
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

Comment: thanks! And there is no package manager with a binary?

Comment: You can find prebuilt binaries but  from 3.0 onward you need build the package to get the contrib modules and they moved a lot of modules in the 3.0 to contrib. If you are ok with 2.4.1 you can . But from 3.0 if you want to work with the contrib modules you have to build it yourself